# Google script copy and moving

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had a script that was working and then it magically stopped. I have been looking for hours for whatever could have caused the problem but am having zero luck. Any suggestions here? The script is suppose to move a row from one sheet to another if a specific cell has a box ticked. Then, if that box is unticked then it sends it back to a different sheet.

I hate asking for this kind of stuff here... but I am really stuck and nobody has been able to help much. I know you all aren't code editors and have bigger fish to fry, but any help would be appreciated... and hopefully someone else can use this :).

```js
function InvoiceArchive() {

  var Accounts = "Accounts";
  var Emailed = "Emailed";
  var Paid = "Paid";
  var Suspended = "Suspended";
  var Closed = "Closed";
  var triggerTrue = true;
  var triggerFalse = false;
  var accountEmailed = 14;
  var accountPaid = 15;
  var accountSuspended = 16;
  var accountClosed = 17;
  var undoArchive = "Emailed";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

//Archiving emailed invoices

  if (sheet.getName() == Accounts && range.getColumn() == accountEmailed && range.getValue() == triggerTrue) {

    var targetSheetE = ss.getSheetByName(Emailed);
    var targetRangeE = targetSheetE.getRange(targetSheetE.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRangeE);
  }

///  

//Archiving paid invoices

  if (sheet.getName() == Emailed && range.getColumn() == accountPaid && range.getValue() == triggerTrue) {

    var targetSheetP = ss.getSheetByName(Paid);
    var targetRangeP = targetSheetP.getRange(targetSheetP.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRangeP);
  }

//Undo paid archiving

  if (sheet.getName() == Paid && range.getColumn() == accountPaid && range.getValue() == triggerFalse) {

    var targetSheetU = ss.getSheetByName(undoArchive);
    var targetRangeU = targetSheetU.getRange(targetSheetU.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRangeU);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }

///

//Archiving suspended invoices

  if (sheet.getName() == Emailed && range.getColumn() == accountSuspended && range.getValue() == triggerTrue) {

    var targetSheetS = ss.getSheetByName(Suspended);
    var targetRangeS = targetSheetS.getRange(targetSheetS.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRangeS);
}

//Undo suspended archiving

  if (sheet.getName() == Suspended && range.getColumn() == accountSuspended && range.getValue() == triggerFalse) {

    var targetSheetU = ss.getSheetByName(undoArchive);
    var targetRangeU = targetSheetU.getRange(targetSheetU.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRangeU);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }

//Moving account to closed

  if (sheet.getName() == Suspended && range.getColumn() == accountClosed && range.getValue() == triggerTrue) {

    var targetSheetC = ss.getSheetByName(archiveClosed);
    var targetRangeC = targetSheetC.getRange(targetSheetC.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRangeC);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
}

///  

//Archiving closed invoices

  if (sheet.getName() == Emailed && range.getColumn() == accountClosed && range.getValue() == triggerTrue) {

    var targetSheetC = ss.getSheetByName(archiveClosed);
    var targetRangeC = targetSheetC.getRange(targetSheetC.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRangeC);
}

//Undo closed archiving

  if (sheet.getName() == Closed && range.getColumn() == accountClosed && range.getValue() == triggerFalse) {

    var targetSheetU = ss.getSheetByName(undoArchive);
    var targetRangeU = targetSheetU.getRange(targetSheetU.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRangeU);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is it not doing?

Comment: Not that it will help with your issue, but did you know that your `triggerTrue` and `triggerFalse` variables are unnecessary? `If` statements are looking for `true`. `range.getValue() == triggerTrue` does the same thing as `range.getValue()` (where the value is true or false) inside an `if` statement. [Some interesting reading on truthy and falsey values](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) that may help you reduce the length of your code in future. :)

Comment: Also, in relation to your problem, have you checked the trigger? Check out the [script dashboard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dashboard) and you might see what's wrong there.

Comment: GClick view > stackdriver error reporting. Are there any error in the last days? If so tell us what it is. If not go to https://script.google.com/home/my and find this project. How many times has it run? If the answer is 0, it's likely a trigger issue.

Comment: @Cooper It's not doing anything at all.

Comment: @s1c0j1 at first we didn't have the tick box and the trigger was based on other inputs. So, we had that as the trigger. Now we have the tick boxes so it's true/false, but we think we will keep that as is incase we change it in the future.

Comment: @Hink it says that it was ran 249 times in the past 7 days with a 0% error rate. 

It was working fine until recently. I wasn't sure if someone on the team edited it or something and screwed it. Everyone says no.. but you still never know,

Comment: It's... working now... I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: Looks like it's time to use the debugger and single step through the program checking all of the intermediate variables as you go.

Comment: Having looked at it, each part of the overall function has several AND conditions. If any of these are not met then the function essentially does nothing. You need to add something like the following to the start of the program to figure out what is going on and then look at the log file:   `Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("sheet.getName() %s, range.getColumn() %s, range.getValue() %s", sheet.getName(), range.getColumn(), range.getValue() == triggerTrue));` or better still enable StackDriver logging for the next time it goes wrong.

Comment: @DakotaMcCarty, my guess was the issue was an authentication issue. When a user has to reset a password or a new scope is added to the script, it will need to reauthenticate, which will happen when a user logs in or the script is run.